# heroku sharing command not working?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I want to add a collaborator to my existing project but the heroku sharing command is failing. This is the error message i have got. I have changed the email ID.

```
partha@PARTHA-PC ~/Desktop/hwhg (master)
$ heroku sharing:add <email>@gmail.com
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https:// help.heroku. com
 !    Or report a bug at: https:// github. com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

Error:       Invalid argument -  git remote -v 2>&1  (Errno::EINVAL)
Backtrace:   C:/Users/partha/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:110:in ``'
             C:/Users/partha/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:110:in `git'
             C:/Users/partha/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:269:in `git_remotes'
             C:/Users/partha/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:216:in `extract_app_in_dir'
             C:/Users/partha/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:32:in `app'
             C:/Users/partha/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:238:in `extract_org_from_app'
             C:/Users/partha/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/base.rb:253:in `org_from_app!'
             C:/Users/partha/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command/sharing.rb:45:in `add'
             C:/Users/partha/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:218:in `run'
             C:/Users/partha/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
             c:/Program Files/Heroku/bin/heroku:29:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku sharing:add <emailID>@gmail.com
Version:     heroku/toolbelt/3.2.1 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3
```

Comment: try passing your app name in explicitly `heroku sharing:add <email> --app <yourappname` - it looks like the CLI is having trouble figuring out your app name based on your git remotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned by John this is the answer...

```
heroku sharing:add <email> --app <yourappname
```

the app name should be mentioned explicitly